# How to create a new Ray Gun with Weird Science?

Tags: savage-worlds

If a character with the Arcane Background (Weird Science) edge takes a new Power, say Bolt, do they need to roll a skill check to create their Ray Gun?

Comment: Remember, bolt requires shooting to use the gun, NOT the weird science skill!

Comment: Thanks but knew that, the question was about making not using one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.  The time spent on the level-up shows devotion and perfection to the new device.  There is no room for error.

From Explorer Edition page 84:

> **New Powers:** Each time a Weird Scientist takes the New Power Edge, he has invented a new gadget. He simply chooses a power and decides what kind of gizmo it’s contained in as usual. He can also repeat a power he’s already taken. A mad scientist might want to create two ray-guns, for example, so that he can use one and give one to a companion.